# Set An Alert on Sharepoint 2013 for multiple list and library

Tags: email, sharepoint-2013

I have some sites with many list and library. I want to know about their changes. set alert for any list and library is very difficult and It takes a long time.
Is there any soloution ?

Answer (score 0):

We can use create alert for all the custom list and document library using C# code or PowerShell script.

The following C# code for your reference.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sp2013"))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            foreach(SPList list in web.Lists)
            {
                if (list.BaseType == SPBaseType.GenericList || list.BaseType == SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary)
                {
                    SPUser user = web.EnsureUser(@"domain\admin");
                    SPAlert newAlert = user.Alerts.Add();
                    newAlert.Title = "My Custom Alert";
                    newAlert.AlertType = SPAlertType.List;
                    newAlert.List = list;
                    newAlert.DeliveryChannels = SPAlertDeliveryChannels.Email;
                    newAlert.EventType = SPEventType.Add;
                    newAlert.AlertFrequency = SPAlertFrequency.Immediate;
                    newAlert.Update();
                }
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Reference:

[Programmatically Creating Alerts in SharePoint](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/programmatically-creating-alerts-in-sharepoint-2010/)

[Create - Edit - Find - Delete SharePoint Alerts using PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/11/managing-alerts-using-powershell.html)